# DB management Framework for insert and update using forms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parsing

After parsing a web site I end up with a data set that needs to be read and updated by a human. I can potentially save the data to any DB but I prefer mongoDB. To read and update the data I can reinvent the wheel and develop a Rest API in node, that uses the mongoDB driver and then develop a front end client with an html form for the user to read and update each document, but since it is 2017, is it there a complete framework that facilitates all this work? or do I need to go nodejs+express+mongo+Rest Client+custom html?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems to be too specific that there would actually be a complete solution somewhere. I think you will have to build it yourself.

If you can speicify more information about what the data is like and what needs to be done with it, it might be helpful.